# Regular Expression to match a string with an even number of 1's and starts and ends with a 0

Tags: regex

I have been trying to create a regular expression for the statement above. The best solution I have come up with so far is 0(0*(10*10*)*0)?. This allows for a single zero and multiple zero's to be matched which I believe is correct but I am just wondering if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: You mean "even number **of**" ones, right? There's not much more to simplify

Comment: Please, show examples of what you have and what you need to get.

Comment: And you would accept just finding a 0 with no 1 pairs? I'm not sure why you have a ? at end. If not, would '0+(10*10*)*0' work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a tiny bit more efficient pattern like

```
^0+((0*10*1)*0+)?$
```

With non-capturing groups:

```
^0+(?:(?:0*10*1)*0+)?$
```

And if you need to allow an empty string:

```
^(?:0+(?:(?:0*10*1)*0+)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mNFUhb/3). As the zeros come before ones in the repeated group, there is a little less backtracking when it comes to matching last zeros.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `0+` - one or more `0`s
- `((0*10*1)*0+)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `(0*10*1)*` - 0+ repetitions of 0+ zeros, `1`, 0+ zeros and then again `1`
  - `0+` - one or more `0`s
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex:

```
^0(?=(?:(?:[^1]*1){2})+[^1]*0$).*
```

Details:

- `^0` - Start of string and (leading) `0`.
- `(?=` - Positive lookahead for:
- `(?:` - A non-capturing group (outer).

  - `(?:` - Another (inner) non-capturing group, containig:
  - `[^1]*1` - A (possibly empty) sequence of chars other than `1` and `1`.
  - `){2}` - Occurring 2 times (a pair of ones).
- `)+` - This group (pairs of ones) can occur several times (even number of ones).
- `[^1]*` - A (possibly empty) sequence of chars other than `1`
- `0$` - `0` and the end of string (terminating 0).
- `)` - End of positive lookahead.
- `.*` - Match the whole string.

If you accept that no `1` chars are present, change `+` after the outer capturing
group to `*`.

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/FvP0Ud/1

You can experiment with this regex, adding / removing `1` chars, at the start
/ end / in the middle of the string and observe whether the string is matched
or not.

Another detail: The above regex allows also digits other than `0` and `1`
and generally all characters. If you want to limit the allowed chars to
just `0` and `1`, change `[^1]` to `0` (in both places).